# Angular js - print views data conditionally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, printing, view, conditional-statements

How can i get this:

```
<div>{{ if(location.path !== '/'){ param }}}</div>
```

How can i print my view data conditionally  or anyway run conditions into `{{ param }}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write expressions to be evaluated inside {{}}.

```
<div>{{location.path !== '/'? param :""}}</div>
```